# "There is already an object named xy in the database azure data"

Tags: sql, database, azure

I am currently learning how to create databases with azure data studio

After creating a database I always get this error :

```
"There is already an object named "Menschen" in the database"
```

and

```
Msg 1778, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
Column 'Wohnorte.Postleitzahlen' is not the same data type as referencing column 'wohnt_ine.Postleitzahlen' in foreign key 'FK__wohnt_ine__Postl__0A9D95DB'.

Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.
```

This is what it currently looks like:

```
create table Menschen (
    Vornamen varChar(30) not null primary key,
    Geschlecht varChar(30) not null,
    Ursprung varChar(30),
);

create table Wohnorte (
    Stadt varChar(30) not null,
    Postleitzahlen character(5) not null primary key,
    Bundesland varChar(30),
);

create table wohnt_ine (
    Vornamen varChar(30) references Menschen,
    Postleitzahlen character(5) references Wohnorte,
    primary key (Vornamen, Postleitzahlen),
);
```

Comment: After correcting the commas, your code should work. (Can't test in Azure SQL right now.) You'll get an error message like *There is already an object named "Menschen" in the database* if you run your code successfully (or create "Menschen" manually), then run your code again.

Comment: Hi melissa, If my answer is helpful for you, please accept(mark) it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> "There is already an object named "Menschen" in the database"

Before you create the table, you can run this query to check if the object name "Menschen" is exist in the database:

```
SELECT * FROM SYSOBJECTS WHERE xtype = 'U';
```

[image]

You can not create the table has the name with exist object.

> Msg 1778, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
>   Column 'Wohnorte.Postleitzahlen' is not the same data type as referencing column 'wohnt_ine.Postleitzahlen' in foreign key 'FK__wohnt_ine__Postl__0A9D95DB'.
>
> Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
>   Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

I tried these code and it works well on my side.  You need to run your statement one by one.

**Step 1**:

```
create table Menschen (
    Vornamen varChar(30) not null primary key,
    Geschlecht varChar(30) not null,
    Ursprung varChar(30),
);
```

**Step 2:**

```
create table Wohnorte (
    Stadt varChar(30) not null,
    Postleitzahlen character(5) not null primary key,
    Bundesland varChar(30),
);
```

**Step 3:**

```
create table wohnt_ine (
    Vornamen varChar(30) references Menschen,
    Postleitzahlen character(5) references Wohnorte,
    primary key (Vornamen, Postleitzahlen),
);
```

[image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can look your database and column in tables of this databases. Certainly,You have a column with same name
or
You can create your column with a different name. For example xMenschen

Answer (score 0):

You first look at your table if Menschen table is exists in your database try to drop your table because you create it before.
Also, you make sure that the row of data in the table you are referencing has the same data type as FK in the table you created.
For example wohnt_ine.Postleitzahlen should be INT and also Wohnorte.Postleitzahlen should be INT(INT data type is just an example. I don't know what is data type in your table.)